# How to handle GCM notifications on Android when the application is turned off?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to push notification. On `Android`, It's [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging).

I have a question when my application is turned off by the user, how to handle `GCM notifications` on `Android` (`Xamarin Forms`)?

This is my code:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseReceiverInstance : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO: handle when App in Background or Foreground
        // How to handle when the user is turned off the app

    }

}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Does the `turned off ` mean that the app has been killed by user?

Comment: @JessieZhang yes!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging GCM has been deprecated. Are you talking about FCM? Or just push notifications in general?

Comment: I'm using [node-pushnotifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications) for push notification on `Android` and `iOS`